# How to use tf.contrib.keras.optimizers.Adamax ?

Tags: tensorflow

I use the tf.AdamOptimizer in tensorflow 1.2:

```
train_opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0004).minimize(error)
```

now I want to replace it with the new [tf.contrib.keras.optimizers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/keras/optimizers/Adamax):

```
train_opt = tf.contrib.keras.optimizers.Adamax(lr=0.0004)
```

But how can I minimize the error?? ( adding .minimize(error) does not work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
train_opt = 
    tf.contrib.keras.optimizers.Adamax().get_updates(loss=cost,constraints=[], params=train_params)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y_, logits = y))

train_params = network.all_params
```